# How can I check If the event listener is running or not ....?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to check if it is possible to identify that the event listener is running or not. For example, I have achieved the following:

```
local function doTurn (event)   
    rotatingRect:applyAngularImpulse(50)   
end  
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", doTurn )
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put print on that function to see if the event is trigger look at this code

```
local function doTurn (event)   
    rotatingRect:applyAngularImpulse(50)
    print("This function is being triggered")
end  
    Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", doTurn )
```